# Cloven Kan fibrations

Tags: higher-category-theory, model-categories, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory

For each groupoid $G$ there is a monad such that the cloven fibred groupoids over $G$ are algebras for this monad. I am looking for an infinite dimensional counterpart: a monad on simplicial sets whose unit is a natural weak equivalence (in the Quillen model structure) and whose algebras are Kan fibrations. A mere existence proof is not good enough, I need a construction. Does Kan's $\mathsf{Ex}^\infty$ construction do this? Are there other monads?

I am looking for (non trivial) model structures on simplicial objects in the effective topos. Unfortunately, the effective topos has no infinite colimits, so the small object argument is useless. The simplicial effective topos has enough injectives and enough projectives. These induce weak factorisation systems, which might be part of a model structure.

Comment: Out of curiousity: what is a cloven fibered groupoid?

Comment: The fibrations of the canonical model structure on groupoids are Grothendieck fibrations. A cloven fibred groupoid is a cloven fibration between groupoids.

Comment: And what is a cloven fibration?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie A cloven (Grothendieck) fibration is one that is equipped with a choice of "pullbacks" (i.e. the data needed to determine the corresponding pseudofunctor uniquely).

Comment: @WouterStekelenburg You may want modify your question somewhat. Garner's small object argument produces a monad on $[\mathbb{2}, \mathbf{sSet}]$ whose algebras are Kan fibrations with chosen liftings, and the unit is even a trivial cofibration.

Comment: @WouterStekelenburg Garner's small object argument _is_ explicit: he constructs the category of (what will become) algebras for the monad and shows that it is indeed monadic. My point was that the construction is infinitary.

Comment: @ZhenLin: the effective topos has a natural number object and power objects. Some infinitary constructions can be internalized, so I don't want to exclude those as potential answers. I don't know if this can be done for Garner's construction.

Comment: Why not have a look at [Garner's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0724) then? But I think internalisation is not likely to yield what you want: the notion of weak factorisation system is not well-behaved in the absence of the axiom of choice; to say nothing of the difference between an internal weak factorisation system and an external one.